# Starting with sockets in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm starting with sockets in C++ but saw 4 different libraries (or includes) that allows one to use sockets, like `winsock.h` `sys/sockets.h`, `sfml` and `boost`. My question is, what is the library/include that I should use?

Comment: Programmers have the annoying knack of coming up with additional answers to the same questions. I'm running a web app that simultaneously deploys multiple apache, tomcat and jetty servers across three different types of virtual machines. I would look for a good tutorial and then just follow whatever they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kind of hilarious, but there's no single widely accepted socket library for C++.

- It's not part of the standard library
- Boost ASIO sacrifices simplicity for high performance
- SFML socket looks pretty nice but it still includes a bunch of other headers
- Windows and POSIX OS sockets have annoying small differences

Some experienced network programmer should write a nice, one-header socket class with all the necessary conditional compilation flags to work on multiple OSes.

Comment: It's certainly not just one header, but I'd like to humbly suggest my own [liblacewing](http://lacewing-project.org) as an alternative for bridging the Windows/Berkeley gap.

Comment: Obligatory http://xkcd.com/927/

Comment: That's nice, thanks for that information.

Comment: Yeah the only real answer is to get it in the standard library... in 1992.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a UNIX-like operating system, use `sys/socket.h`.  It's part of the [open standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xns/syssocket.h.html).  For Windows, you'll need to use the Winsock library, so you'll have to include `winsock2.h` instead (here's [the docs on how to use that library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: I forgot to mention that those include files are only for Berkley sockets and not Boost.

Comment: Thanks a lot, about sfml and boost is a third-party library right?

Comment: Note: Unix sockets and Winsock can be made source-compatible with not too much work (a few `#ifdef`), as long as you don't need high-performance event handling.

Comment: Well, you can have high performance event handling on pretty much any operating system except from Windows using Berkeley sockets.  But if you need scalable sockets on Windows, you have to rewrite everything (or use a high level library that does both for you.)

Comment: So to start with sockets the best way is using winsock (if i'm using windows). When i searched in internet for boost tutorials i don't saw anything about it, i only saw about winsock and sys/socket.